# Closing application in Android - delay

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I programmed a button into my android app that called the finish() method when I click it. But somehow it does not close until after a 5-6 second delay.

I am recording sensor values for a particular movement of the phone. The problem is when there is a delay after I close, it records those unnecessary values and the analysis is messed up.

So any idea why the UI takes so long to respond? I am very new to Android and I can't find this online. I don't do too much computation- as and when sensors change I record the value onto a file in the sdcard memory. Sometimes if I run the program for too long, it just crashes and I don't know why.

Please help! I would also like to know if there's a manual way to kill through the computer? something like Ctrl+C for DOS?

Comment: how this is a programming related problem?

Comment: its not a programming related problem.. but it does have to do with the IDE.. I can't post this on any other stackexchange, can I?

Comment: Does this problem arise on the emulator or on the phone? Do you see this delay on the phone too?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a keyboard shortcut to close a running Android application?

There is no concept in Android of "close a running Android application".

The Esc key in the emulator behaves as the BACK button to (typically) close the current activity.

> I have a button that I use to kill the application in my phone and that has a huge delay.

No, you don't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I think I wrongly phrased that sentence. I programmed a button into my app that called the finish() method when I click it. But somehow it does not close until a 5-6 second delay. The problem is that I am recording sensor values for a particular movement and when there is a delay after I close, it records those unnecessary values and the analysis is messed up. So would you know why the UI takes so long to respond? Thanks!

Comment: @Imelza: "But somehow it does not close until a 5-6 second delay." -- that's unusual. It may be that your sensor data is overloading your device. You may need to specify a higher delay (e.g., `SENSOR_DELAY_UI`). Also, bear in mind that whatever you are doing during sensor data processing, by default, occurs on the main application thread -- while you are doing that work, the UI is frozen.